# Treeview plugin how to remember collapse settings

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery Treeview plugin and I need to remember collapse and expend settings to give back the same view as it was before updating the page.

Is there some library which can serialize collapse/expand settings to cookie memory?

Comment: I would suggest just not refreshing the page so that you don't have to re-build the tree every time.

Comment: It looks like the jQuery Treeview Plugin already has this functionality. Include the cookie plugin then use the `persist` option.

Comment: @Kevin B, I have simplified my case, actually i'm using ajax, some part of page are reloading and then I need come back to the same treeview look.

Comment: are you using a lazy-loading treeview? (meaning it only loads the nodes that need to be visible as you open tree elements)

Comment: @Kevin B, I'm not using lazy-loading and you're right, there's persistent for jquery treeview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Treeview plugin already has persistence functionality (thanks to Kevin B).
The code is:

```
$('#tree').treeview({ persist: "cookie"});
```

Comment: Please let me know where should i use this line.